# Bhagwan Shiva worship

Tags: shiva, worship

I have one doubt.
If person has not accumulated any good sanchit karmas.

Will he still get blessings simply by worshipping mahadev with water and milk?

Comment: See Karmas are nothing infront of Shiva. "Yoga Agni Karma nivarti". Just like how a fire turns wood into Ash within no seconds, through the fire of Yogic knowledge, you can burn all your Karmas to Ashes within 1 second. Yes he can get blessings with the way you mentioned. Understand - what you offer for Shiva doesnt matter. Offer him milk, water, pongal, rice, chicken, or even boar. What matters is purity and devotion. Purity devotion to Shiva cleanses and frees one from all sins.

Answer (score 3):

Gita 9.16 says (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> Whosoever offers Me, with devotion, a leaf, a flower, a fruit, or water--that I accept, the pious offering of the pure in heart.

It is purity of heart, of intentions - offering out of love, not for begging of something - that is important, not what is offered, that makes the difference.